# How are integer types converted implicitly?

Tags: c, misra

The following code fails on a MISRA check. The concrete error message is:

> (MISRA-C:2004 10.1/R) The value of an expression of integer type shall
>   not be implicitly converted to a different underlying type if it is
>   not a conversion to a wider integer type of the same   signedness

```
typedef enum _MyEnum { One, Two } MyEnum;
MyEnum MyVariable;

int foo(void)
{
    int result = 1;

    if (One == MyVariable)  // fails here with MISRA-C:2004 10.1/R
    {
        result = 2;
    }    
    return result;
}
```

- Why is the logical expression converted?
- What is converted here?
- Why does the code pass the MISRA check, when I swap `One` and `MyVariable`?

*Edit*: The compiler is a TI "MSP430 C/C++ Compiler v4.0.0" with included MISRA rules check.

Comment: I already have bad toughts about this MISRA thingy. What you are doing is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'd second the compiler bug hypothesis

Comment: Does it produce the same error/warning for `if (MyVariable == One) {}` ?

Comment: @wildplasser Please read the last sentence of my question.

Comment: Oops. I only read code, so it seems ;-)

Comment: My compiler does not generate an error but the static analysis tool does, regardless of the order in the `if` expression.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suspect a compiler bug. What compiler are you using? [This post](http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/t/144535.aspx) mentions a compiler bug causing Misra 10.1/R failures when using TI's compiler.

Comment: The bug in the link referes to another problem. It's the same MISRA check that fails, but there is it for errornously treatment of an array element. It's not related to a order of enum and variable.

Comment: I know. I just mentioned it as an example of a Misra check which failed due to a compiler bug.

Comment: This is a bug as confirmed by TI.

Comment: This is not related to the problem at all.

Comment: We already agreed on that. What is your point? @harper accepted the answer, which I presume means that my suspicion was correct.

Answer (score 6):

There is no bug in the MISRA checker, it behaves correctly. You get this error because the C standard is flawed and illogical.

There are two items:

- `One` is an *enumeration constant*. The standard §6.7.2.2/2 states that this shall be compatible with `int`, no exceptions.
- `MyVariable` is an *enumerated type*. The standard §6.7.7.2/4 states that this should be compatible with char, a signed integer type or an unsigned integer type. Which type that applies is implementation-defined behavior.

In your case, the implementation-defined enumerated type appears to be equal to unsigned int.

So the code attempts to implictly convert a variable of signed int to unsigned int, which is a violation of MISRA 2004 10.1.

MISRA-compliant code should be `if (One == (MyEnum)MyVariable)`.

Comment: "The standard" is the C standard? If MyVariable is an unsigned int, why does the check succeeds when I swap One and MyVariable?

Comment: @harper Yes, the C standard ISO 9899:2011 (C90 is identical). Well, the swap must be a bug then, it should give you an error no matter which order you use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the compiler internally handles `enums` as `unsigned integer`, as long there is no negative value within the `enum`.