# MISRA Violation Rule 10.1 and Enums

Tags: c, enums, misra

First off, this is similar to: [How are integer types converted implicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582523/how-are-integer-types-converted-implicitly) but with a different MISRA warning.

The compiler does not generate a MISRA error, but the static analysis tool does.  I have a ticket with the tool manufacturer in progress.

Given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum Color {RED, VIOLET, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, ORANGE};

int main(void)
{
  enum Color my_color;
  my_color = BLUE;
  if (my_color == YELLOW)  // Generates MISRA violation, see below.
  {
     printf("Color is yellow.\n");
  }
  else
  {
     printf("Color is not yellow.\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The static analysis tool is generating a MISRA violation for the `if` statement:

```
MISRA-2004 Rule 10.1 violation: implicitly changing the signedness of an expression.
Converting "4", with underlying type "char" (8 bits, signed),
to type "unsigned int" (32 bits, unsigned) with different signedness.
```

Is the compiler correct (not identifying the defect) or the static analysis tool?

Comment: Same code, same error, your error report is just a bit more verbose. I don't see any difference between your code snippets.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what reply you got back from your tool-vendor, but this looks like the tool is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the C language specification, the type of the expression:

```
typedef enum Colors {RED, VIOLET, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, ORANGE} Colors_t;
```

is a `signed int`.

Also according the language, the value of an enumerated item is the smallest unit that can contain the entire enumeration.  So in the above enumeration, `BLUE` has the type `signed char`.

The static analysis tools are reporting a MISRA violation when a variable of `Colors_t` is compared to `BLUE`:

```
Colors_t my_color;
if (my_color == BLUE) // This generates a MISRA violation.
```

The violation is `signed int` compared to `signed char`.

Also, the enumeration items can be mixed with other enumeration types without error, *since the enumerations are not a unique type*:

```
typedef enum Tree_Species {REDWOOD, CYPRUS, PALM, OAK, JUNIPER, SEGUARO} Tree_Species_t;
Tree_Species_t my_tree;
my_tree = BLUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that someone (your compiler or the static tool) believes that your enum is not the same size and/or signedness as an *int*.

My Green Hills compiler has an option --short-enum (Use Smallest Type Possible for Enum) that will select a *char* type for your example above.  Does your compiler have such an option? Is it enabled? Does the compiler default enums to a "non-standard" value?

In my experience, by default static tools follow the language spec pretty well by default, meaning that it should expect an enum to be int-sized.  (See this link for reference: [What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)).  Since most static tools snoop your compiler command-line usage, your compile-time options may be convincing the static analyzer that your enums are smaller than *ints*.

I suggest reviewing your compiler and static analyzer documentation thoroughly to resolve the conflict.  Keep a close eye on your build process, too (compile-time options, defaults, etc).

Answer (score -2):

It is likely as a result of the declaration of `my_color`

```
enum Color my_color;
```

Try removing 'enum' from this:

```
Color my_color;
```

The static analyser probably reckons that you are declaring a separate enum, thus the 10.1 violation.
Since its then a different type, the MISRA rule forbids assigning one type to another.

Comment: -1 Uh? This is C, not C++. After `enum Color {A, B, C};` there is no type named `Color` defined (as I believe there would be in C++).