# Why does 'typeof enum constant' generate a warning when compared to a variable of enum type?

Tags: c, gcc, enums

I have the following code.

```
typedef enum {FOO, BAR} Baz;

int main()
{
    Baz f1 = FOO;
    typeof(FOO) f2 = FOO;
    return (f1 == f2);
}
```

My compilation using `gcc -Wextra foo.c` generates a warning saying

```
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:7:13: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
 return (f1 == f2);
             ^
```

My gcc version

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582523/how-are-integer-types-converted-implicitly  (bad duplicate though, since the accepted answer is incorrect)

Comment: It's worth noting that `typeof` is a gcc-specific extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quoting directly from `C11`, chapter `§6.7.2.2`, *Enumeration specifiers*,

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined.

So, the *type* of the enum variable is not defined by standard. It can be any of the above.

OTOH, `FOO` being an enumeration constant, `typeof(FOO)` will give you `int`, as the standard mandates

> An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type `int`.

which is being used as the type for `f2`.

Now, if enum is `unsigned int` on your implementation, so is `f1` and,  `f2` is `int`.

Next, you get the warning.

> *How can I fix this problem?*

Well, if you change the type of `f2` to `typeof(Baz)`, which gives the type of the enum, then both the types of `f1` and `f2` will be same. Compiler will be happy.

<kbd>[SEE LIVE HERE](http://rextester.com/IMTYG21024)</kbd>

Comment: I've made a minor update. The enumerated type can be compatible with `char` or with *any* signed or unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 16):

It's a known "bug" in the C standard. Enumeration *constants* are guaranteed to be of type `int`, while enumeration *variables* are of implementation-defined integer type.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733714/584518) for references.

Comment: Why'd they do that instead of just letting the normal promotion rules apply (i.e. they can be any type which promotes to int)?

Comment: @Random832 No rationale was ever given in C90 or later standards. I would suppose they would like to save memory by allowing byte-sized enums, plus in theory it would be handy to have a one byte enum in many cases. In practice you can never write code which relies on it though, because such code would be non-portable. This is just one of many really dumb things in the C standard, just like for example the various implicit type promotion rules.

Comment: Yeah, but a byte can promote to an int. So in practice, in almost any expression FOO would still act like an int even if its type really is that of the enum.

Comment: The way I think of it is the enum type has an explicit enumeration of all the values it can hold. But using enum values as bit flags that get bit wise or'd together is common practice and results values that are not in that explicit list.