# Unpermitted operand to operator '|' [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.1, required]

Tags: c, macros, misra

Observed below Misra warning for 10.1 rule. It says "Unpermitted operand to operator ‍‍‍`|`.

How to avoid this warning ?

This is misleading as `|` is not being used in the statement.

```
#define C_BYTE unsigned char
C_BYTE SendStatus;
#define SEND_PENDING   0x10

SendStatus &= (C_BYTE) ~ ((C_BYTE) SEND_PENDING);
```

**EDIT:**

I am using Misra 2012 to check QA-C warnings. compiling the code using a batch file.

```
#define BYTE unsigned char
#define REQUEST  0x01
#define PENDING  0x10
#define D_PENDING  0x20
#define SEND_PENDING (PENDING|D_PENDING|REQUEST)

struct cp {    
  BYTE SessionStatus;
  BYTE SendStatus;
};
```

Case 1:

```
BYTE fun2( void )
{
    cp.SendStatus &= (BYTE) ~ ((BYTE) SEND_PENDING); //Warning observed for this line

    if((cp.SendStatus & (BYTE) REQUEST) != 0u)
    {
        cp.SendStatus &= (BYTE) ~ (BYTE) REQUEST;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```
void fun1(void)
{
    BYTE ChkStatus = (cp.SendStatus & (BYTE) SEND_PENDING); //Warning observed for this line

    if ((bool)ChkStatus)
    {
        cp.SendStatus |= ((BYTE) REQUEST);
    }
    else
    {
        cp.SendStatus |= ((BYTE) PENDING);
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't a complete example. You don't show the definition of `CCP_BYTE`.

Comment: Yes, It's C_BYTE, not CCP_BYTE. Changed

Comment: It still is not a complete example. Provide a full function. Also, with what tool did you check your code?

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: How to avoid this warning?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736432/misra-2012-violation-type-mismatch-rules-10-1-10-4 for a complete answer to your situation

Comment: `#define REQUEST  0x01U` etc. Do **not** cast any literals to `uint8_t` and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify as below to avoid this warning.

```
#define REQUEST    0x01u
#define PENDING    0x10u
#define D_PENDING  0x20u
```